# How to use fragment identifiers in path helpers in phoenix webframework?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, fragment-identifier

Is there a way to add a fragment identifier to a path helper?

I try to link back from my login page to the about section in the landing page.

```
<a href="localhost:4000/#about">ABOUT</a>
```

Using this path helper, I only get back to the landing page:

```
<li><a href="<%= page_path(@conn, :index) %>">ABOUT</a></li>
```

But I would like to get to the about section at the following path:

```
localhost:4000/#about
```

I tried to combine the path, but without success:

```
<li><a href="<%= page_path(@conn, :index) <> "#about" %>">ABOUT</a></li>
```

Thank you in advanced for any help!

Comment: Your code works for me. What error are you getting?

Comment: I don't get an error, but the page is just not reloading somehow...

Answer (score 0):

One cannot nest the double quotes:

```
<a href="<%= page_path(@conn, :index) <> "#about" %>"
```

the above obviously results in an error, because it reads as shown below, strings are denoted:

```
#       ⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓      ⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓
<a href="<%= page_path(@conn, :index) <> "#about" %>"
```

To make is work, use the [`~s`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Kernel.html#sigil_s/2) sigil:

```
<a href=~s|<%= page_path(@conn, :index) <> "/#about" %>|
```

Comment: There's no nesting here. The outer quotes are in the HTML, not the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can just move the #about string out of the interpolated expression:

```
<li><a href="<%= page_path(@conn, :index) %>#about">ABOUT</a></li>
```

Comment: That creates the correct link but somehow clicking it does not load in my case

Comment: What about adding a slash, like “/#about”?

Comment: Without slash is better, but clicking still does not trigger a reload